# Save/restore browser's cache?

Tags: caching

I intend to write a browser-based game, and noticed that an option would be to save/restore games in the browser cache, like this game does:

play.freeciv.org

How would I go about saving/restoring files to a cache manually, though? Would that work in such a case? (If I manage somehow to copy a file, erase it from cache and put it back manually, would it work? Or would I find some permission/date/etc issue?). I know almost nothing on saving files manually to a client's. Which brings me to the second part of the question:

What would I need to read to manipulate such files programmatically? I use php/js, know some of both (somewhere between the "poor" and "knows what a recursive functions is" levels, I would imagine...).

The initial idea is to give an option to a player not to lose a savegame/etc in case the cache is erased (a̶s̶ ̶h̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶g̶a̶m̶e̶).

Thank you in advance.

The game has been updated and now it offers more options to manage savegames. It could only save up until a certain space limit was reached (cache space that seems to be browser specific.), or delete all savegames. (Pretty Spartan)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked, but I seriously doubt it's saving data to the browser cache. It's most likely using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), or maybe just simply using cookies if your session is saved on server.

Comment: Well,, guess what? I am a Civilization afficcionado, and went there for a quick game. Guess what? they added a bit of the functionality missing before, as, for example, being able to either delete all savegames or keep them all, till you get a "can't save. cache full" message. Now you can download/upload savegames, or  "delete oldest". I wouldn't know where to start to look in their source, but, well, why don't I try :)